# how recursion works in this C # program?

Tags: c#

```
using System; 

class RevStr { 

  public void displayRev(string str) { 
    if(str.Length > 0)  
      displayRev(str.Substring(1, str.Length-1)); 
    else  
      return; 

    Console.Write(str[0]); 
  } 
} 

class MainClass { 
  public static void Main() {   
    string s = "this is a test"; 
    RevStr rsOb = new RevStr(); 

    Console.WriteLine("Original string: " + s); 

    Console.Write("Reversed string: "); 
    rsOb.displayRev(s); 

    Console.WriteLine();
```

} 
}

Answer (score 2):

Since the recursive call is first as long as the string has contents it will recursively call itself with one less character. Once it's all out of characters the calls unwind printing one character at a time. It prints backwards because if you take the call stack (for a smaller string)

```
displayRev("test")
displayRev("est")
displayRev("st")
displayRev("t")
displayRev("") // unwinds here
```

So if you look at the first letter of each and write it down it becomes, tset, the reverse of test.

Answer (score 1):

This is a recursive method that prints a string reversed. To print a string `str` reversed, first print `str` without the first character reversed(recursive step) and then print the first character.

For example to print `abcd` reversed, print `bcd` reversed which is `dcb` and then print `a`(the first character).

Comment: This is not technically correct.  It does not print 'bcd' reversed at all.  It prints only a single character at a time.  The recursion is effectively what is allowing us to print it backwards.  It manages each segment of the string separately and then does a `Console.Write()` of only the first character from the string that was pushed onto the stack.

Comment: @Mcarthey - This is the recursive step. I am essentially explaining the logic behind. Not the technical details that a stack is used. When you print `bcd` again `cd` is reversed and `b` is printed.

Comment: @McArthey, you, re wrong, the explanation is perfect, there are no moving targets in it, it's just a static definition.

Comment: @Mcarthey - By print 'bcd' reversed I mean that you call the procedure recursively with 'bcd' and it's job is to print 'bcd' reversed.

Comment: @Petar Minchev Thanks for clarifying.  I only didn't want the OP to become confused.

Answer (score 1):

it´s throwing an exception.

example:

```
displayRev("bla");
displayRev("la");
displayRev("a");
//Now it gets an error
//The string.Length "a" is bigger than 0 (it´s 1)
//in displayRev(str.Substring(1, str.Length-1)); he wants to make a SubString beginning at the
//index 1 (the Second character), but the string contains only 1 character 

//if-Statement have to look like:

if(str.Length > 1)  
      displayRev(str.Substring(1, str.Length-1)); 
    else  
      return;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the easiest way to think of recursion is as a Stack.  In fact, if you search for Stack and recursion you'll see many ways to implement recursion using a Stack.
In your code you are effectively stripping the first character and then pushing the remainder onto the stack.  When the condition is met that it needs to "pop" the stack it executes your `Console.Write()` statement for each element on the stack.  In your case it means that it is going to print the first character of the string that was pushed onto the stack.  Remember that a Stack is handled in LIFO (Last In, First Out) order so this results in handling the strings in reverse order.

See if this link helps: [The Animation of Recursion, Simple String Reversal](http://www.animatedrecursion.com/simple/reversal.html)

Comment: The stack is not the easiest way if you see recursion for one of the first times. The main idea is dividing the problem into subproblems and then solving them (possibly by the same function).

Comment: @unkulunkulu I did preface the comment with 'maybe' since I only wanted to provide another way for the OP to look at the solution.  It certainly helps to have many perspectives and not mentioning the concept of a stack would, in my mind, not do service to a discussion on recursion.

Comment: Yeah, exactly for this reason I like all the answers for this question :)